# viewport height makes a snappy flicker when scrolling on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, viewport

So I used a lot of vh in my website, in mobile browsers when you scroll down the page the browser's address bar disappears and when you scroll back re-appears (such as chrome)

my issue is when this happens everything in my page resizes due to differences that adress bar makes in my document's height

is there any work-around for this such as calculating your current device vh at first using jQuery and then converting everything to px instead of vh?

or any other suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I battled with this exact same issue a few days ago and the solution I came up with was something like this:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
   var $vhElement = $("#vhElement");   //Your element with 100vh
   var height = $vhElement.height();   //Get rendered height in px
   $vhElement.css("height", height + "px");  //Override vh height with px height
});
```

If you have multiple elements that need this, you can apply a class to all of them and use the following

```
 $(window).on('load', function() {
   var $vhElements = $(".vhElement");   //Your elements using vh
   $vhElements.each(function() {
       var height = $(this).height();   //Get rendered height in px
       $(this).css("height", height + "px");  //Override vh height with px height
   });
});
```

Comment: so I have to write this for every element I have in my page? that's just not so much of a global approach :( maybe for one or two element but unfortunately there's a whole lot of elements on my page using vh

Comment: I added one that works with classes if you can afford to put a class on all elements that use vh.

Comment: it's not really an optimal solution but I guess it will work for now, thanks